# ngModelChange or change event angular 8 is crashing the application

Tags: html, angular, typescript, crash

I've this simple of a selection component implementation below:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngFor="let value of values">
        <select
                [name]="value.id"
                [(ngModel)]="value.selected"
                (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
                class="form-control">
            <option [ngValue]="null">Selecione</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of value.items"
                    [ngValue]="item">
                {{item.title}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>

 public onChange(event) {
        console.log(event)
    }
```

when calls ngModelChange function the application crashed. I already tried to use change event too but the same thing happens, without change event function the component works normally.

crashed screen:
[image]